# How to prove that $g' $ is not bounded on the interval $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g:= R→ R$ be defined by $g\left(x\right):=x^2 \sin \left(1/x^2\right)$ for $x$ is not equal to 0, and $g\left(0\right)=0$. Show that g is differentiable for all $x$ in $R$. Also show that the derivative g' is not bounded on the interval [-1,1].

So far, I have: when x is not equal to 0, $g'\left(x\right)=2x\sin \left(1/x^2\right)-2/x\left(\cos \left(1/x^2\right)\right)$. when $x=0$. $g'\left(0\right)=\lim_{x→ 0}\frac{g\left(x\right)-g\left(0\right)}{\ x-0}=\lim_{x→ 0} x\sin \left(1/x^2\right)=0$. How to show that g' is not bounded on the interval [-1,1]? [Hint: $x_n= 1/\left(2nπ\right)^{1/2}.$]

Comment: There's a $1/x$ term in $g'(x)$. So it should be unbounded.....

Comment: What is your definition of "differentiable", if you haven't _already_ shown that $g$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ is differentiable because, as you wrote, it has a derivative everywhere.

Now consider the sequence $x_n>0$ defined by $\frac 1{x_n^2} = 2\pi n$. Then what if $g'(x_n)$?